# Parametrization of a tetrahedron?

Tags: surface-integrals, parametrization

I need to do a surface integral over the surface bounded by $x + 2y + z = 4$ and the coordinate planes. How do you go about parametrizing this surface? My first thought was with $x = x$, $y = y$, and $z = 4 - x - 2y$, but there are no numerical bounds for x and y which will only capture the surface within the first octant. Is there another parametrization? Also, I realize it would be way easier to use the divergence theorem, but the question here is to confirm the theorem by evaluating it as a surface integral and with the theorem. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: An alternative: use barycentric coordinates with triangle $(4,0,0)$, $(0,2,0)$ and $(0,0,4)$.

Answer (score 2):

The complete boundary surface $\partial T$ of your full tetrahedron $T$ is a so-called $2$*-chain* consisting of four triangles. The total surface integral $\int_{\partial T}$ is then the sum of  four integrals computed individually.

A parametrization of the "roof" of $T$ is given by
$$(x,y)\mapsto(x,\ y,\ 4-x-2y)\qquad \left(0\leq y\leq {4-x\over2},\  \ 0\leq x\leq4\right)\ ,$$
whereas a parametrization of the "floor" of $T$ is given by
$$(x,y)\mapsto(x,\ y,\ 0)\qquad \left(0\leq y\leq {4-x\over2},\  \ 0\leq x\leq4\right)\ .$$
In both cases you have to check that the outward normal comes out right. I leave the parametrization of the two "walls" to you.

Comment: There is an error I think. The domain of $x$ should be between $[0,4]$ not between $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Futurologist: You are right. Thank you for spotting the slip.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is right, you parameterize it as 
$$x=u$$
$$y=v$$
$$z=4-u-2v$$
Where $$0\leq u \leq 4$$ $$0\leq v \leq \frac{4-u}{2}$$ I have just renamed the parameterizing variables.